# Linq to Entities - SQL “IN” clause for integer column

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

```
Select * From Employee where Id in (1, 2, 5, 7)
```

Now how can I write this in LINQ query using `from where select`

```
var ids = new List<int>() {1, 2, 5, 7}    
from employees in _EmployeeRepository.Table
where employees.id *in list*
select employess
```

In case of string contains will do. How to achieve for integer column. I know I am missing very basic thing.

Comment: Why would `Contains` not work for integer columns?

Comment: use ids.Contains() in where condition.

Answer (score 6):

```
var ids = new List<int>() {1, 2, 5, 7}    
var result = from employee in _EmployeeRepository.Table
where ids.Contains(employee.id)
select employee;
```